# Insert buttons in public registration forms

Tags: extension, forms

I am working on a module extension which allow users to Register via different social media/oauth accounts. These login buttons need to be added below all the forms which are anonymously available.

What is the best way I can achieve this?

- These buttons can be defined in a small smarty template file which can be inserted into the form.
- or can be created via JavaScript, which can be inserted into the page.

Please suggest what should be the right way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Smarty:

According to the CiviCRM [Javascript Reference](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Javascript+Reference#JavascriptReference-ProgressiveEnhancement), public-facing pages should follow the principle of Progressive Enhancement.

"Front-facing pages like contribution pages and event signups should adhere to the standards of PE. All front-end pages should be fully functional with js disabled."

Comment: Can you please refer to me an example where the insertion is being used?